Navigation with minimum turning radius
I have a map with waypoints, the waypoints are stored as (x,y) tuples. I am trying to generate a path between these waypoints but I require the path to have a constrained turning radius. I have tried using SmacPlannerHybrid, but the problem I am facing is that since the goal has no pose, the planner tries to take weird paths to reach the goal. Is there a planner which can plan constrained paths ignoring the final goal orientation?


Unfortunately, the Smac Hybrid-A* Planner does not yet allow for goal-directed non-specificity, but there are efforts to implement it (#3789, #4127).
In the meantime, you can configure the NavFn Planner to use the use_final_approach_orientation parameter to set the orientation of the last pose of the path generated by the planner to the approach orientation instead of the goal orientation. This parameter is documented on the Nav2 documentation website but is not used in the default Nav2 parameter file.
Then to configure the minimum_turning_radius, use the Contrained Smoother plugin in the smoother server.
Example configuration:
planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: False
      allow_unknown: True
      use_final_approach_orientation: True

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoother_plugins: ["SmoothPath"]

    SmoothPath:
      plugin: "nav2_constrained_smoother/ConstrainedSmoother"
      reversing_enabled: true       # whether to detect forward/reverse direction and cusps. Should be set to false for paths without orientations assigned
      path_downsampling_factor: 3   # every n-th node of the path is taken. Useful for speed-up
      path_upsampling_factor: 1     # 0 - path remains downsampled, 1 - path is upsampled back to original granularity using cubic bezier, 2... - more upsampling
      keep_start_orientation: true  # whether to prevent the start orientation from being smoothed
      keep_goal_orientation: true   # whether to prevent the gpal orientation from being smoothed
      minimum_turning_radius: 0.40  # minimum turning radius the robot can perform. Can be set to 0.0 (or w_curve can be set to 0.0 with the same effect) for diff-drive/holonomic robots
      w_curve: 30.0                 # weight to enforce minimum_turning_radius
      w_dist: 0.0                   # weight to bind path to original as optional replacement for cost weight
      w_smooth: 2000000.0           # weight to maximize smoothness of path
      w_cost: 0.015                 # weight to steer robot away from collision and cost

      # Parameters used to improve obstacle avoidance near cusps (forward/reverse movement changes)
      # See the [docs page](https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-constrained-smoother) for further clarification
      w_cost_cusp_multiplier: 3.0   # option to have higher weight during forward/reverse direction change which is often accompanied with dangerous rotations
      cusp_zone_length: 2.5         # length of the section around cusp in which nodes use w_cost_cusp_multiplier (w_cost rises gradually inside the zone towards the cusp point, whose costmap weight equals w_cost*w_cost_cusp_multiplier)

      # Points in robot frame to grab costmap values from. Format: [x1, y1, weight1, x2, y2, weight2, ...]
      # IMPORTANT: Requires much higher number of iterations to actually improve the path. Uncomment only if you really need it (highly elongated/asymmetric robots)
      # See the [docs page](https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-constrained-smoother) for further clarification
      # cost_check_points: [-0.185, 0.0, 1.0]

      optimizer:
        max_iterations: 70            # max iterations of smoother
        debug_optimizer: false        # print debug info
        gradient_tol: 5e3
        fn_tol: 1.0e-15
        param_tol: 1.0e-20

